# Does $\sum_{r=0}^n 1=n+1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, solution-verification

Here's my question:

Is the following true? $$\sum_{r=0}^n 1=n+1$$

Here is my area of confusion. Looking at this superficially it would indeed seem to be the case that the result is true, but the result contradicts my understanding of what the sum from $r=a$ to $b$ of a constant means.

In the case of
$$\sum_{r=1}^n 1$$ I would make sense of the summand by thinking of it as

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^0$$
so the summand would still be a function of $r$. But in the case of
$$\sum_{r=0}^n 1$$
I can't think of it as
$$\sum_{r=0}^n r^0$$
as $0^0$ is undefined. So, is the result correct, or is meaningless?

Note: I know that $\lim_{x\to0} x^x=1$, but it doesn't seem right to apply this to our case of $0^0$; I seem to remember a different value that can found for the 'value' of $0^0$ by taking a different limit.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it’s true. There are $n+1$ integers in the set $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, and you have a term $1$ for each of them, so $$\sum_{r=0}^n1=\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{n+1\text{ ones}}=n+1\,.$$ There is no reason to look at $0$ powers at all. However, for the record $0^0=1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I thought of that, but doesn;t a summand have to be a function of the variable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's going on here.  You have a series sum, which is perfectly well defined, but you choose to replace the summand with an expression that is not well defined at one value of the index, and you're wondering whether that has any impact on the original series sum?

Comment: Let it be the constant function $f(r)=1$

Comment: It is a function: it’s the constant function $f(r)=1$ for all $r$.

Comment: No....(to Brian's question)  the summand does not.  Any more than you must have a function of $x$ in $\int\limits_a^b 1\ dx$, except to set $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, now I see where my mistake was, thank you!

Comment: @BrianTung my mistake was in assuming the summand had to involve $r$ in some way, so I thought it must be $r^0$.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: Ahh, no, that is not the case.  That's true of functions in general; they need not depend explicitly on every argument.

Comment: @BrianTung thank you for your understanding and clarifiaction, I can't belive I didn't know this after  doing summations and calculus for 2+ years :)

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: Well, it's not a problem that comes up a lot ordinarily, I suppose. :-)

Comment: Count your fingers $1$ to $10$, that's $10$ fingers, count the $1$'s, $1$ to $n$ that's $n$ $1$'s. If you start counting from $0$, that's an extra $1$.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: You’re welcome!

Comment: @nolemonnomelon I think you misunderstood my area of difficulty/mistake. My mistake was assuming the summand had to involve $r$ in some way, so I thought it must be $r^0$. Thanks for trying to help me though :)

Comment: $\sum_{r=0}^0 1 = 1.$

Comment: @mjw Thanks, with the help of the Brians I now understand that :)

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I saw you got it cleared up with Brian M Scott and Brian Tung it’s just a different way of looking at the sum:) Also $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n 1 = \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n+1} 1$ because as mentioned above $1$ as a function is independent of $r$ and the latter would work for $r^0$. So it also depends on the set you choose to sum over, since $r^0$ is ‘undefined’ at $0$ you can choose a set over which it always defined.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can approach the serie as

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} 1 = 1 + \sum_{r=1}^{n} 1 = 1 + n$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, my mistake was in assuming that the summand had to involve $r$ in some way, and has already been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have been answered in the comments, but here is another way to understand it. The symbol
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n}f(r)
$$
can be given a precise definition in the following way. First we define
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{0}f(r):=f(0) \, ,
$$
and second for $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ we define
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n}f(r) := f(n) + \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}f(r) \, .
$$
This definition, which references itself in a somewhat strange way, is known as a 'recursive definition'. It might seem kind of circular at first, but if we try unravelling what it means with an example, then we see that there is no issue:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{2}f(r)=f(2)+\sum_{r=0}^{1}f(r)=f(2)+f(1)+\sum_{r=0}^{0}f(r)=f(2)+f(1)+f(0) \, .
$$
You might want to try proving by induction that
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n}f(i)=f(0)+\ldots+f(n) \, .
$$
Here, we are dealing with the function $f$ such that for all $x$, $f(x)=1$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^{n}f(i) &= f(0)+\ldots+f(n) \\
&= \underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{\text{$n+1$ terms}} \\
&= n+1 \, .
\end{align}
One other thing you said in your question is that the summand has to be a 'function of $r$'. This kind of phrasing is very common in mathematics, but is confusing, in my opinion. The reason for this is that the letter used  to represent a function is irrelevant. If I let $f$ be the function defined by $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$, then this simply means that the output is always the square of the input. The letter $x$ is just being used to tell us this fact in a concise way. Bear in mind that technically $f$ is the function, whereas $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$ at the point $x$. This subtle point is almost always glossed over in A-level mathematics, but becomes more important later on.

Comment: Hi Joe, it's great to have you back. How are your A Levels going? Have you decided whether to go to uni in the coming year or defer?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: Hi. Thank you for the warm welcome. One more History assessment to go and then I've finished my A-level 'exams'. I'm thinking of going to Bath or Durham next year.

Comment: Ok, very nice. My exams will be over in a couple of weeks. What are you planning on studying?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: Maths! By the way, are you are in Year 12 or Year 13?

Comment: I'm in Year 12 but in my school generally the students do GCSE's and A Levels in Years 10 and 12 respectively, whatever your ability (unless you really can't manage it of course).